# How to add a link for Facebook post message "name" parameter in Graph API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook wall post, how to add URL(link) for "name" parameter.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               StrImg, @"picture",
                               StrName, @"name",
                               emailBody, @"description",
                               actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                               nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another parameter to dictionary with key as link

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Thank you venu...i have another doubt, how to set new line for "caption " or "description" parameter...please give me your idea...

Comment: Facebook doesn't, allow u to use new line

Comment: Welcome, Accept the anwser if it is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"]; 
ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:message forKey:@"message"];
[newRequest setPostValue:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:imageURL forKey:@"picture"];
[newRequest setPostValue:attachmentName forKey:@"name"]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:attachmentCaption forKey:@"caption"]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:attachmentDescription forKey:@"description"]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:href forKey:@"link"];
//[newRequest setPostValue:@"http://www.foo.com/bar.swf" forKey:@"source"];
[newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)]; 
[newRequest setDelegate:self]; 
[newRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Or you can set the parameters in the meta tags of the shared ressource:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"]; 
ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:message forKey:@"message"]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:href forKey:@"link"]; 
[newRequest setPostValue:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"]; 
[newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)]; 
[newRequest setDelegate:self];
[newRequest startAsynchronous];
```

With:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head>
    <title>Foobar</title>
    <!-- Facebook meta tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="meta title"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.foo.com"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.foo.com/bar.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="meta site name"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="123"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="meta description"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <!-- <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.foo.com/bar.swf"/> -->
    <!-- <meta property="og:video:width" content="1200"/> -->
    <!-- <meta property="og:video:height" content="800"/> -->
    ...
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You can upvote or even accept my answer. Just click the upvote sign or the check box underneath the upvote sign (both are on the left of the answer). Same applies to @Venu 's answer : ]